# how do you select and then output a REPLACED word?

Tags: sql

Supposed I have the query:

```
SELECT names, color
FROM my_dataset
WHERE date='2013-07-18'
```

And this outputs:

```
John    0
David   1
Mary    0
Bill    0
Joe     2
```

The problem is that the 'color' column are Intergers.  Is it possible to feed in a key/feature map somewhere so the output can be (0=GREEN, 1=BLUE, 3=RED) instead??

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your sql dialect. For example, you could use `case` in MS SQL

```
select names, 
       case color 
           when 0 then 'green' 
           when 1 then 'blue' 
           when 2 then 'red' 
           else null 
       end as color 
from my_dataset
```

In Oracle, there's a `decode` function.

Or just make a table with key/name mapping and join it with your data.

Comment: +1 for the correct solution and mentioning Decode in Oracle and giving alternative solution. ENUMS at the application level can also be used in relation to Color column in DB.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CASE`:

```
SELECT 
  names,
  CASE color 
    WHEN 0 then 'Green'
    WHEN 1 then 'Blue'
    WHEN 2 then 'Red'
  ELSE '???' END 
As 
  Color
FROM 
  my_dataset
WHERE 
  date='2013-07-18'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `decode`

```
SELECT names, DECODE( color, 0, 'GREEN',
                             1, 'BLUE',
                             2, 'RED',
                      'UNKNOW'
                    ) as true_color
FROM my_dataset
WHERE date='2013-07-18'
```

Comment: Just as a note: this is PL-SQL only function and not available in T-SQL (MS SQL).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `When case` clause by giving an alias to numbers

```
SELECT names,(CASE color
                     WHEN 0 THEN 'GREEN' 
                     WHEN 1 THEN 'BLUE'
                     WHEN 3 THEN 'RED'
                     ELSE '' END
                ) AS color
FROM my_dataset WHERE date='2013-07-18'
```

Comment: What is the reason for sub-query?